# Python Telegram Bot Read Large Message

Tags: python, telegram, python-telegram-bot

I am trying to create a Telegram bot using [python-telegram-bot](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot) that will read in a large message (~12K characters) and save the output to a file.

The relevant code I have is:

```
updater = Updater(token='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

def runMe(update, context):
    received_message = update.message.text
    print("Received message with length %d" % len(received_message))
    # Save (full) message to file

arg_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, runMe)
dispatcher.add_handler(arg_handler)
```

However when I do this, Telegram splits the messages into chunks of 4,096 (max message size)

> Received message with length 4096
>
> Received message with length 4096
>
> Received message with length 4095 **(Not sure why this is 4095)**
>
> Received message with length 24

How do I modify the bot so that although the messages are sent in chunks, I am able to combine all of these to create the single original message with no modification to the formatting.

My original idea was to create a global variable and append each message chunk to a list but I am not sure how to achieve this short of sending a command like /startMessage and /endMessage to signify when the message is sent. This method seems inefficient.

Comment: I don't know how this API works but surely you could just append the incoming data to your file.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I do not want to always append it. The next time I send a message, i want it to replace the contents of the file.

Comment: In that case you'll need to figure out how to detect either the start or end of an incoming message stream. Try appending everything to a file for test purposes and look at the resulting output to see if there's a way to detect either BOF or EOF

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an idea could be to use a global variable and append all chunck to that, using `message_id` to understand when message is different.

```
updater = Updater(token='XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX')
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher

all_message = {
    message_id = 0
    text = ""
}

def runMe(update, context):
    global all_message
    if update.message.message_id == all_message["message_id"]:
        received_message = update.message.text
        all_message["text"] += received_message 
        print("Received message with length %d" % len(received_message))
        # Save (full) message to file
    else:
        all_message["message_id"] = update.message.message_id
        all_message["text"] += received_message

arg_handler = MessageHandler(Filters.text, runMe)
dispatcher.add_handler(arg_handler)
```

The problem could be when you consider the message ended for re-send, store or process it. Is not a great solution but you could consider the previous message ended when you go in the `else` condition, or you can check if chuck is <4095-4096, or again add a special character at the end of the message